# Webfont looks terrible in Chrome while good in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webfonts, antialiasing

I have a menu on a page that uses a custom webfont. It is a condensed font type and has a shadow. When I render it with Firefox it looks OK, but in Chrome it is hard to read. This is some antialiasing problem.

Firefox:

[image: In Firefox it looks good]

Chrome:

[image: In Chrome it looks bad]

I already tried to switch off the shadow and played with -webkit-font-smoothing but it didn't help. What else can I try?

The relevant CSS is here:

```
#submenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #9a60a0;
}

#submenu li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px 10px 12px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #9a60a0;
  height: 22px;
}

#mainmenu{
  width:1000px;
  height:60px;
  margin:0px auto;
  font-family:LeagueGothicRegular,Arial, verdana,Century gothic,  sans-serif;  
  font-size: 18px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    src: url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.svg#LeagueGothicRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Which font file format are you loading?

Comment: post your `@font-face` rule please. also font rendering is dependent on OS in addition to browser. many fonts when converted for use on the web do not look great (webfonts such those from Google are specifically optimized for web display).  Often you can make it look better by tweaking `font-size`, just keep in mind that what you see in Chrome on Windows is not always at all similar to how it will render in Chrome on OS X.

Comment: Is this a google font?

Comment: It's not a Google font, I just downloaded it and converted with FontSquirell
I posted the @font-face rule
I only tested it on Windows yet, but I'll test it on Linux. I don't have a MAC so I can't test OS X right now